# What does '-' do as a boolean expression

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean-expression

What I generally wanted to do is to check when `(x-3) > i`.

I got the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10, i;

    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(x-3)
            printf("%d, ", x);

        x--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I accidentally wrote `(x-3)` instead of `(x-3 > i)`, and I got these results:

**10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4,** 
The number 3 is missing. I understood that it is something that somehow connected to the `x-3` expression, but I haven't find a clear answer yet in Google.. 
Does anyone have an idea? Thanks...

Comment: The layout implies that the `x--` is inside the body of the `if`, but the braces say otherwise...

Comment: @pat I know, that's the Dev-C++ compiler indentation... Anyways, edited

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, an expression is considered to be *false*  if its value is 0 (zero),<sup>†</sup> all other values are considered to be *true.* Thus, the expression `x - 3` is *true*  if and only if `x != 3` which is why you see `3` being skipped in your loop.

This also applies to pointers: The null pointer is *false,* all other pointers are *true*. You are going to see code like this:

```
if (some_pointer) {
   do_something();
}
```

Here `do_something();` is only executed if `some_pointer` is not the null pointer. Similarly, null pointer checks often look like this:

```
if (!some_pointer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Encountered a null pointer\n");
    abort();
}
```

Because the logical not operator applied to a pointer yields 1 (true) for the null pointer and 0 (false) for all other pointers.

---

<sup>†</sup> More pedantically, it is considered to be *false* if and only if it compares equal to `0`. There is a subtle difference in this wording as e. g. the null pointer may not have the *value* 0 but it compares equal to the *integer literal* `0`.

Comment: Thank you mate! That was very helpful.

Comment: @rolory, but notice that many consider it a good style if you still compare the number against zero: `if (x - 3 != 0) …`. Less  confusion.

Comment: The C spec [does not require a null pointer to be 0](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html), that is just the most common implementation of it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Doesn't matter. In a “logical” context, all pointers except for the null pointer are true, regardless of what value the null pointer has.

Answer (score 4):

It just means the substruction operator.:)

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 **In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the
>   expression compares unequal to 0**. In the else form, the second
>   substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the
>   first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is
>   not executed.

In this if statement

```
 if(x-3)
```

expression `x - 3` always evaluates to non-zero value except when `x` is equal to `3`.

So when `x` is not equal to `3` this statement

```
printf("%d, ", x);
```

is executed and outputs the current value of `x`.

When `x` is equal to `3` this statement is skipped.

The result demontsrates this explicitly

```
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4
                    ^^^ 3 is absent
```

The loop iterates 15 times but outputs only 14 values of x. The value of `x` equal to `3` is skipped due to the expression in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Morning friend! So if(expression) only follows through when the expression is equal to true. In C (and C++ and elsewhere..) **0 = false** and **all other numbers = true** (the exception is `null`)

Therefore when `x = 3`, `x-3 = 0`. So `if(x-3)` equates to false. Thus the program never reaches the print statement.

As you go along, you're decrementing x from 10 so eventually x will equal 3, at which point you won't get to the print statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Detail: `NULL` is false even if it does not have a binary pattern of all zeros.  `-0.0` evaluates as false too.

Answer (score 0):

when you write `if(x-3)`,if the conditional expression evaluates to 0,it is considered false,and the code inside the if brackets will be discarded.if it evaluates to non-zero value,it is considered true and the code inside is executed.

Comment: Please pay attention to correct whitespace usage, and sentence capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

when using a `if()` statement, the body of the `if` statement is entered or not depending on the true/false of the expression within the `()`.

Note: in C, a 0 is the same as a false.

when x is 3, then the expression `x-3` is 0/false, so the body of the `if` is not entered.